# Can orm2 create a table automatically?

Tags: node.js, orm, node-orm2

I use Hibernate in J2ee, when the datebase has't table the framework can create table and when fields changed it can update datebase, Can orm2 be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/wiki/Syncing-and-dropping-models) wiki pages explains, orm2 can create the database tables if they do not exist. Update of an database table is possible by another library, however i haven't tried this: https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/issues/103